# How to Add action link in view using razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a required field, `string attribute { get; set }` in a class and want to set its value in Razor. Is something like the following possible?

```
@model.attribute = "whatever'
```

Comment: To answer the question *Is something like the following possible?*, yes but it'd be pointless

Comment: your content and question dont make sense

Comment: Why do you want to programtically assign the model value in view? It is not making sense to me.

Comment: The only thing that matters is what gets posted back. Simply assigning a value to the model property does not necessarily mean that it will survive the round trip; the value needs to actually be rendered to the page as a value for an input. So, if you set this value on the model before you actually render the field for the property, it should work, but that further begs the question of what's the point, and why not not just do this in your controller?

Answer (score 1):

Close. `@model` is how you declare the model for your view. Your view should have a `Model` property, so you can do this:

```
@{
    Model.attribute = "whatever";
}
```

Comment: Practically i dont think we assign model value in a view like this. It is not going to be useful

Comment: It would be better if the value was set in the controller code, yes. But you can change model values in the view, which the OP asked.

Comment: Yes I agree. Not sure what is the intention of modifying the model while rendering.. :)